# Filtering .each with json

Tags: jquery, json, each

```
$.get('/shared/ajax/blog.asp', function(data){
jsonArray = $.xml2json(data)
$.each(jsonArray.channel.item, function(i, item) { 
var title = item.title
```

In this data I have a variety of different item.category options available. In my each function I would like to exclude items that have a category of UT or UK. At the end of the function I have a simple if statement that gets rid of it but it is still counting as an "i" in the function above. I need the newest 8 posts excluding UT and UK posts and how it is now I am only getting 6 results because a UK item.category is excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain an internal counter instead.

```
var counter = 0;

if (category == "UT" || category == "UK") {
    return;
}
array.push(item);
counter++;
if (counter == 5) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all the "UT" and "UK" before iterating:

```
var items = jsonArray.channel.item;
items = $.grep(items, function() { 
    return $(this).category != 'UT' && $(thi).category != 'UK'; 
});
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
```